# .env file undefined using require('dotenv').config();

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dotenv

Having trouble with getting dotenv to pick up my .env file

Here is my file structure:

```
├── app.js
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
├── routes
│   └── index.js
└── start.js
│   
└── .env
```

And here is my start.js:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection
  .on('connected', () => {
    console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${process.env.DATABASE}`);
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`);
  });
```

inside my .env is as follows:

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@livewelldb-aqoul.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Unfortunately, when running my node.js app I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:520
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

this is happening because dotenv does not seem to be able to find my .env file for some reason. when I run `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI);` I get undefined.

No idea why. Most people with this issue have one of the following problems:

- they don't run their program from the root directory
- their .env is not in their root directory
- their .env is named incorrectly, eg "config.env"
- their .env is formatted in something other than UTF-8

I do not have any of these problems. I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Double check your .dotenv file to make sure there isn't a typo. If everything looks good, try adding 'path' to the dotenv config, like this: ```require('dotenv').config({path: './'})```

Comment: For whatever reason I can't break line in my comments on mobile. My other suggestion is to make sure you're in your project root when you start your app. This is because dotenv uses `process.cwd()` to set the path to dotenv.

Comment: Unfortunately your first suggestion did not help, and as mentioned in my OP I have already made sure I am running my program in the root directory.

Comment: Can you post your entire .env file? If that's the entire thing, you're not actually declaring your environmental variable. It should look something like... `MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@livewelld...`

Comment: That was my full .env file, as per the tutorial I am trying to follow. I have added the MONGO_URI= part, with and without quotes around the url, and it doesn't make a difference. still undefined.

Comment: dotenv returns an error that you can inspect. Usually that helps understand why your environment variables are not being populated. There’s also a DEBUG flag that can help.

Answer (score 1):

specify your .dotenv file name in the package upon loading the app

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. It was suggested by Jay Kariesch as well yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **`.dotenv`** file name.

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'relative/path/to/your/.env'})
```

Comment: I do not have a `.dotenv` file anywhere, only a `.env`. I cannot see any reference to such a file in the dotenv readme either. Did you mean `.env`? Also, I have tried the relative path suggestion and it does not change anything.